# Invalid Signature for Tezos transaction

Tags: transactions, wallets, signature

I am writing full custom wallet software for Tezos in C# and got the following raw transaction:

**UnsignedHex:** 
*008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d00*

**HashPreimage:**
*03008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d00*

**Hash:**
*8541434de6c77aaa3e6a4d4e341717a5c96b14e990183fd33e8157ef53f38579*

**Signed:**
*008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d0049ff4a47599e0c65447182eca4c900893a74de3ca24c26708fc9d4bf79891ca384b0d5f98618bc3acec4f0c6bffd002de6fd839a418f47e83404aed285fc0235*

When I try to inject the raw signed transaction ('Signed') with the node rpc I get the response:
*[

    {

        "kind": "temporary",

        "id": "failure",

        "msg": "Error while applying operation  oozXCEKTUFcw8PHcrskvuWphiH1kNz12eohX1mp8AKinJU9fPYS:\nrefused (Error:\n           The operation signature is invalid\n)"

    }

]*

I can verify the signature (secp256k1) of the transaction against third party tools and it verifies (that is purely that the 'Hash' value is signed correctly). I used the node rpc 'Forge' endpoint to verify the correct serialization with following JSON:
            *{ "branch":"BKiXcfN1ZTXnNNbTWSRArSWzVFc6om7radWq5mTqGX6rY4P2Uhe",

            "contents":[{

            "kind":"reveal",

            "fee":"1300",

            "gas_limit":"10100",

            "storage_limit": "300",

            "public_key":"sppk7ZjMvKgUwnjYZKoQEYaNhorr1NJxmqgHLjExsP3uq98XKChFius",

            "counter":"2622172",

            "source":"tz2G2Zy3sgYCuh1EQqrx9Q62CcpSkgcLPPDt"},{

            "kind":"transaction",

            "fee":"1520",

            "gas_limit":"10500",

            "storage_limit": "300",

            "amount":"300000",

            "counter":"2622173",

            "destination":"tz2FwBnXhuXvPAUcr1aF3uX84Z6JELxrdYxD",

            "source":"tz2G2Zy3sgYCuh1EQqrx9Q62CcpSkgcLPPDt"}]

            }*

And also was able to verify UnsignedRaw => Hash with python code:

```
from pyblake2 import blake2b
import binascii
operation=binascii.unhexlify('008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d00')
h = blake2b(digest_size=32)
h.update(b'\x03' + operation)
digest = h.digest()
print(binascii.hexlify(digest))
=> 8541434de6c77aaa3e6a4d4e341717a5c96b14e990183fd33e8157ef53f38579
```

It almost seems like a bad error message. Can anyone help me figuring out what the problem with my transaction is?

P.s. in a second run with the same software I was able to generate a fully valid transaction: *007fc1ecd6a56046aaaeab78bbfa1c889eb8f502b66c720bf1ac3b40ee9ecf6d6b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02c09a0c000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d00231176ec0cf55e3f04d5de633c33b38a6370ad2c37fd31c4c45e12ec9f1466753c8137f5dee8105bd5cc3d4ce780f51ec01d5adb21893e75eef4b960189818a3*

A third run was again deemed invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/d644dda5c9dbdecee52d1aa259235510fdc2d4ee/include/secp256k1.h#L483-L513

There are two valid EC points that correspond to the same signature, but some blockchains restrict the usage to one of those two EC points to avoid malleability (= it is easy to convert the signature to the other signature value, and thus create a second valid transaction which would have a different transaction id without haveing access to the private key).

Edit:
The corresponding valid transaction is:
008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46b01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480f940adc85a001f44eac02010238244743822921db1661fc7306c3044faac1e373906fdb5582d9454352b3b31c6c01549a0cde570a49b9200680341a6c78e87635480ff00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d0049ff4a47599e0c65447182eca4c900893a74de3ca24c26708fc9d4bf79891ca384b0d5f98618bc3acec4f0c6bffd002de6fd839a418f47e83404aed285fc0235
This was created without re-signing and without access to the private key.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you revealed public key just once and make sure you properly incement counter.

Also, take a look at [Netezos](https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos), C# Tezos SDK. Here is an example of how to forge, sign and send a transaction:

```
var key = Key.FromBase58("edskS9DjUKo8ogBBU8LeU...");

var rpc = new TezosRpc("https://rpc.tzkt.io/carthagenet/");
var head = await rpc.Blocks.Head.Hash.GetAsync<string>();
var counter = await rpc.Blocks.Head.Context.Contracts[key.PubKey.Address].Counter.GetAsync<int>();

var forge = new LocalForge();
var bytes = await forge.ForgeOperationAsync(head, new TransactionContent
{
    Source = key.PubKey.Address,
    Counter = ++counter,
    Fee = 10_000,
    GasLimit = 20_000,
    StorageLimit = 20_000,
    Amount = 1_000_000,
    Destination = "tz1KhnTgw...",
});

var sig = key.Sign(new byte[] { 3 }.Concat(bytes).ToArray());
var op = bytes.Concat(sig.ToBytes()).ToArray();

var tx = await rpc.Inject.Operation.PostAsync(Hex.Convert(op));
```

If it doesn't work even with Netezos, check if your RPC node is synced and up to date.

Comment: Based on the JSON in the original question and the status of the sender address [link](https://tezos.id/accounts/tz2G2Zy3sgYCuh1EQqrx9Q62CcpSkgcLPPDt), does counter & reveal look ok?

Comment: I suggest you use TzKT explorer, because it shows more useful info, including operations failed in mempool https://tzkt.io/tz2G2Zy3sgYCuh1EQqrx9Q62CcpSkgcLPPDt/operations. So, what I see is two failed in mempool operations with counters `..72`, `..73` from `12:01:49 UTC`. In your question I see JSON with the same counters BUT with the branch https://tzkt.io/BKiXcfN1ZTXnNNbTWSRArSWzVFc6om7radWq5mTqGX6rY4P2Uhe - from `12:55:12 UTC`. So, I assume that you tried to send the operations with the counters `..72`, `..73` which had already been in mempool.

Comment: Generally speaking, your JSON looks fine, but the fact that there were failed "clones" in the mempool may cause the error you described.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The transaction in the mempool is the successfull transaction that I was referring to, however it is now invalid because the branch is outdated, if that were to block future transactions it would complete block the account and should be rendered a critical bug in the Tezos node, so I don't think that it should be the cause of the error.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to test signing with Netezos since I retrieve the signature from an HSM and can not get access to the private key.